# Calling a function on click via JavaScript/jQuery on button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my JavaScript:

```
function privacy(current)
{
    var $this = $(current), 
    $scope = $this.closest('.uk-button-group'), 
    value = $this.val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/privacy.php',
        data: {key: value },
        success: function () {
        }
    });
}
$(function() {
    $("#privacy1, #privacy2, #privacy3").click(function() {
        privacy($this);
        alert('A button has been clicked!');
    });
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div class="uk-button-group">
    <button class="uk-button" id="privacy1" value="1">Public</button>
    <button class="uk-button" id="privacy2" value="2">Protected</button>
    <button class="uk-button" id="privacy3" value="3">Private</button>
</div>
```

When I click on one of the buttons, it should call the privacy function and alert me that a button has been clicked but it doesn't. Can anyone help me and show me what's wrong with my code? Much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Opening the console would have shown you where the error is...

Comment: **tip** You can use the common class to bind to shorten the code **Ex:** `$('.uk-button').click`

Comment: `privacy($this);` $this is undefined, it's time to start using your console...

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to javascript, I'm doing my code in notepad, could you please tell me where the console is located? Thanks

Comment: @SieuPhan console is in browser, press F12 to open it

Comment: Thank you @A.Wolff I feel so lame for trying to reference a variable that was undefined. I'll watch the consoles next time for my errors thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have any identifier `$this`, you probably need to change `$this` with `$(this)` or simply `this` to pass the event source object

```
privacy(this);
```

OR

```
privacy($(this));
```

Comment: Or just `this` as it is placed in a jQuery object within the function

Comment: Thank you! I just realized I that it was `this` instead of `$this` which was undefined. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :-

```
privacy(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/pqdgT/

```
$(function() {
    $("#privacy1, #privacy2, #privacy3").click(function() {
        privacy($(this));
        alert('A button has been clicked!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your  [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/fAJJv/1/)

And here is the refined code

```
function privacy(current)
{
    var btn = $(current), 
    scope = $(btn).closest('.uk-button-group'), 
    value = $(btn).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/privacy.php',
        data: {key: value },
        success: function () {
        }
    });
}
$(function() {
    $("#privacy1, #privacy2, #privacy3").click(function() {
        privacy(this);
        alert('A button has been clicked!');
    });
});
```

Please avoid reserved keywords while naming variables - [Here is the list of reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

And be careful with your syntax and feel free to use the browser console.